# PHP sql statement to search databse for user names

Tags: php, sql, search

I am trying to construct an sql query to search my database for users. It is supposed to help users to find other users on my website to find friends.

I did some research because I knew I did not want:

```
$query = "SELECT userName, userID FROM user WHERE userID = $userName ";
```

Because it would not be an effective search if they had to type the users exact name in to find them.

After doing some research I decided to try the like term with % symbols in front and back so it could be the name with lets say numbers before or after and it would show up.

The example I found online formatted it like this:

```
$query = "SELECT userName, userID FROM user WHERE userID Like '%{$userName}%' ";
```

but when I executed this query while implemented on m y website, I ran into problems of it returning to many results. It returned results that did not include anything within my search term.

I also tried the above search query with out the brackets since I did not understand why I needed them but I got the same results.

Any suggestions on how to make the search a little stricter using the above command query?

Or any other suggestions for how I should search my database for a user to friend?

Comment: You are having userID in your LIKE clause and the variable you are matching against is $userName.Why so?It should be WHERE Username LIKE '%$userName%' and I am not sure why you have used braces around $userName.

Comment: And don't forget about [`Bobby Tables`](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @techie_28 I thought your change would have cracked it. Def needed to make it userName not userID. But I am still getting results as stated above.

Comment: % this is the wild card character @Mike.If wrap the variable with it then it will search in a whole.However if you want to search it with begining then you can use '$username%'.It will match the records starting with that user name like 'mike%' will fetch you 'mike','mike.tyson187','mike_lewis02' and so on.Isnt it what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`%` sign](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) is for wildcards. So if `$userName = 'apple'` your query would match `apple`, `applepie`, and `crabapple` but not `appl`.

If you want an exact match remove the `%s` or the LIKE altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. also why are you using braces..

```
$query = "SELECT userName, userID FROM user WHERE username Like '%$userName%' ";
```

Comment: As stated in my question I have tried this already without the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the strings

`Apple`
`iApple`
`Apple Product`

If you type `Apple`

**Like '%{$userName}%' "**

**Returns**: Will return you `Apple`, `iApple` , `Apple Product`
**Reason**: The `%` on both side indicates it will accept any text before and after your search term

**Like '{$userName}%' "**

**Returns**: Will return you `Apple` and `Apple Product`
**Reason**: The `%` on right side indicates it will accept any text after your search term

**Like '%{$userName}' "**

**Returns**: Will return you `Apple` and `iApple`
**Reason**: The `%` on left side indicates it will accept any text before your search term

**Like '{$userName}' "**

**Returns**: Will return you `Apple`
**Reason**: No `%` will restrict the search to the search term

**Further More**

I believe your query should be

```
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($userName);
  $query = "SELECT userName, userID FROM user WHERE userName Like '%{$username}%'";
```

Comment: I am doing this:

$queryF = "SELECT userName, userID FROM user WHERE userName Like '%{$userName}%' ";

And it is returning a lot of names it should not

Comment: What is your search and what are the results. can you post them ?

Comment: Using this query:

$queryF = "SELECT userName, userID FROM user WHERE userName Like '%{$userName}%' ";

I search for: Mark

And I get:

hoppy
test
jason
Bekka
Mark


etc including others that do not have the name mark in it at all.

Comment: are you sure only this query is getting executed ? Print the query itself and see what is the actual query being executed.

Comment: Yes only that query is being executed. I believe it is a formatting problem in php because I changeed it to an equal and took out the % and made it an = and it only returned the name if i typed in exactly

Comment: That is the expected behaviour of `=` but if you use `%` it ignores part of string on the side you are using it.